# Downloading Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I am starting to develop apps for Android. As you know, i need to download Android SDK to my computer, but i cannot because developer.android.com is not being opened. Is there another way to download this SDK? Thanks so much.

Comment: Sounds like a technical support request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try android SDK offline version. you can visit http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
download from this link, for windows download exe pack, that will open a window which will download SDK , Follow guide given in above link...

Answer (score 0):

some of the google ip addresses are blocked in Turkey. So it is not possible to download android sdk from its original location. You may try to download it from torrent, usenet or from sites like rapidshare.